# How can I redirect ngrep output to file

Tags: bash, ngrep

I am running ngrep on machine to listen to request and response. How can I redirect its output to a file?

I am doing something like this:-

```
sudo ngrep -q -t "/dummy/v1/xyz" -W byline -d any port 1231  > ngrep_output.txt
```

But when I am doing  `tail -f ngrep_output.txt` on other screen, I can't see anything.

Once I kill the above process then only I could see the contents in file.

So, it looks like it keeps the result in buffer somewhere? Is there a way I could redirect my output in realtime to the file?

Comment: I haven't tried this, but looking at the source, you could try either to [not specify `-q`](https://github.com/jpr5/ngrep/blob/master/ngrep.c#L800) or specify [`-l`](https://github.com/jpr5/ngrep/blob/master/ngrep.c#L311).

Comment: yes -l worked. Thanks. You can put this in the answer if you want. I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any document describing the commandline arguments to ngrep, but [the source code indicates that the `-l` option turns off output buffering](https://github.com/jpr5/ngrep/blob/master/ngrep.c#L311).